# Way to use bisect module for sets in python

Tags: python-3.x, bisection

I was looking for something similar to `lower_bound()` function for sets in
python, as we have in C++.

Task is to have a ds, which inserts element in sorted manner, storing only single instance of each distinct value, and returns the left neighbor of a given value, both operations in `O(logn)` worst time in python.

python: something similar to bisect module for lists, with efficient insertion may work.

Comment: sets are unordered, and the standard lib does not offer tree structures. Maybe you could look at sorted containers (3rd party lib): http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/

Comment: take a look at this link: https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html

Comment: @SomayyehAtaeiKachouei i have read it, but it only works for lists, in which sorted insertion will take O(n), which is of no use to me.

Comment: Looks like you want a TreeSet or Binary Search Tree, none of which have a builtin class in Python, AFAIK.

Comment: Python's `set` is far closer to a C++ `std::unordered_set` than a C++ `std::set`.

Answer (score 0):

sets are unordered, and the standard lib does not offer tree structures.

Maybe you could look at sorted containers (3rd party lib): http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/ it might offer a good approach to your problem.

Comment: thanks for your reply, actually using third party library would not be possible for my task as it is restricted.